# First-timer at Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: command-line

I know nothing, and the related answers I read are not intelligible to me.
Do I have to be Linux literate before I try to install Ubuntu?
Sounds like a ton of work and time.
Is it possible otherwise?

This is what I tried:
I downloaded, from ubuntu.com, version 20.04. When I looked into downloads, I found version 18 something!
Even so, I clicked right on it to run it; I thought it is the way to install it, as I have done before with other things.
The prompt didn't show me any software/program with which to run/open it.
I have downloaded Rufus, as one tutorial indicated.

What do I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Go over these steps: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview You have downloaded an *.iso file. You need to put it on an USB stick (with Rufus or something else), stop the computer, stick the USB in, and start. If it starts with the Ubuntu installer from the USB, good. If not, you need to update the BIOS settings regarding Boot Devices (so that it boots from the USB (and maybe regarding secure boot and maybe regarding legacy boot vs EFI boot)... Search for each step (on this site or elsewhere) if you get stuck on any of them.

Comment: Also, have a plan what you want with your Windows installation and your documents on it: keep it? Throw it all away? If you want to keep windows and install Ubuntu alongside it, you will need to pay attention. Follow the installer's steps, but whenever you are uncertain, google your question. Don't go trial and error if something is not clear enough. Pay close attention to each description and label. When in doubt, you can cancel the installer process almost any time.

Comment: Also, save your documents from your disk to some secondary place (e.g. external hard drive), just to be sure that you will still have them even if you accidentally nuke your windows.

Comment: Ah, this is the guide to use the installer: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview The part where you can keep your Windows will come at this step: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space

Comment: Ubuntu is an operating system like Windows XP or Mac OS X or Windows 7. It's not a programme like Word or Google Chrome or Microsoft Flight Simulator that you download and install on windows and then run

Comment: Unless they put it into Virtualbox :) But I did not assume that...